# Marionette.CollectionView for a select box

Tags: backbone.js

When I ma using backbone.marionette.js , want to populate data in select box . But what is the best way to  populate data in select box ?

Answer (score 2):

if you really want to use marionette for this, don't use a collectionview. the option tag is very simple, and trying to get an ItemView to render each tag is a big waste, honestly. too much code for no benefit.

```
<script id="select-template" type="text/html">
  <% _.each(items, function(item){ %>
    <option value="<%= item.id %>"><%= item.name %></option>
  <% }) %>
</script>

var SelectView = Marionette.ItemView({
  template: "#select-template",
  tagName: "select"
});

var c = new MyCollection();

var sv = new SelectView({
  collection: c
});

someRegion.show(sv);
```

Comment: Probably should include the [source for this answer](https://gist.github.com/gillesruppert/5875554#comment-852750).